# Repeat switch statement until it has a valid answer

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm a beginner trying to make a text adventure game in JavaScript, and I need to repeat a switch statement until the user enters a valid answer:

```js
opts = prompt("Do you want to TALK or LOOK?").toUpperCase();

switch(opts) {
  case "TALK":
    mes = "Is anyone in charge here?";
    speech = "Our leader is in the big building.";
    talkNot();
    break;
  case "LOOK":
    window.alert("The buildings are quite simple, and the doorways are much shorter than you. You notice, however, that there is a very tall, thin building at the end of the street.");
    break;
  default:
    window.alert("That's not an option.");
}
```

Any answers would be super helpful - thanks!

Comment: For case: look and default your logic is good, for talk i guess you have defined talkNot(), so what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the code with some function and `callback` the function  in default statement

```js
function run(){
opts = prompt("Do you want to TALK or LOOK?").toUpperCase();

switch(opts) {
  case "TALK":
    mes = "Is anyone in charge here?";
    speech = "Our leader is in the big building.";
    console.log('talk')
    //talkNot();
    break;
  case "LOOK":
    window.alert("The buildings are quite simple, and the doorways are much shorter than you. You notice, however, that there is a very tall, thin building at the end of the street.");
    break;
  default:
    window.alert("That's not an option.");
    run() //callback 
}
}

run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [`do ... while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) structure.

```js
let next = false
do {
  let opt = prompt("Do you want to TALK or LOOK?").toUpperCase();
  next = false
  switch (opt) {
    case 'TALK':
    case 'LOOK':
      break;
    default:
      next = true
  }
} while (next)
```